# jaspersoft hide chart types link in dashboard

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to remove the "Chart Types" link from the dashboard but am not able to do so. I tried adding

```
.show_chartTypeSelector_wrapper { display: none; }
```

to overrides_custom.css of my(default) theme, but it does not reflect. I am not sure if its being picked up. Also I restart jasper server after every change just to be sure

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the reports opens in iFrame, the override_ccustom css file is not effective there.

**The resource (css) is loaded with the follwoing URL:**

.../reportresource?resource=com/jaspersoft/jasperreports/highcharts/charts/resources/ jive.highcharts.vm.css&jr.dynamic=true

In order to modify any property, you have to chnage into the resources located into ythat jar.

**Steps to do that:**

1. Download and open jasperreports-highcharts-5.x.x.jar file
2. Open the jar as archive with 7zip.
3. Go to com.jaspersoft.jasperreports/highcharts/charts/resources
4. Download jive.highcharts.vm.css file
5. Locate class jive_chartSettingsIcon
6. add display: none into it and put it back to the archive location

Now replace the jar and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding to my overrides_custom.css, the following style:

```
.jive_chartSettingsIcon {
    display: none;
}
```

(without the need of changing the archive)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set a property in the jasperserver.properties file:

```
com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.interactive=false
```

This should to the trick, removing the chart type possibilities from every report displayed in the dashboard
Hope it helps
Fran